# workbox offline response from IDB instead of cache

Tags: response, workbox, localforage

I am building an vueJs application with a service worker. I decided to use Workbox with an InjestManifest method to had my own routes.

on fetch when online : 
1- answer with the network
2- wrtting body to IDB (through localforage)
3- send back the response

here everything is working perfectly, the sw intercepts the fetch and come back with an appropirate response, IDB contains rigth details.
response sent back to fecth when online:
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3005/api/events", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

the issue is when I go offline.
my intention id to connect to Locaforage and retrieve the content and build a response.
The issue is that this response is not considered as appropriate by Fetch who then reject it. Console.log confirms that the .catch in sw is working but it looks like the response it sends is rejected.
here is the console.log of the response I am sending back to fetch when offline;
Response {type: "default", url: "", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

I do not know if fetch is not happy becasue the url of the repsonse is not the same as on the request but workbox is supposed to allow responding with other resposnes than the ones coming from cache or fetch.

here is the code

```
importScripts('localforage.min.js')

localforage.config({
  name: 'Asso-corse'
})
workbox.skipWaiting()
workbox.clientsClaim()

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('https://fonts.(?:googleapis|gstatic).com/(.*)'),
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'googleapis',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 30
      })
    ]
  })
)
workbox.routing.registerRoute( new RegExp('http://localhost:3005/api/'), function (event) {
  fetch(event.url)
    .then((response) => {
      var cloneRes = response.clone()
      console.log(cloneRes)
      cloneRes.json()
      .then((body) => {
        localforage.setItem(event.url.pathname, body)
      })
      return response
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.warn(`Constructing a fallback response, due to an error while fetching the real response:, ${error}`)
        localforage.getItem(event.url.pathname)
        .then((res) => {
         let payload = new Response(JSON.stringify(res), { "status" : 200 , 
    "statusText" : "MyCustomResponse!" })
         console.log(payload)
        return payload
        })
  })
    })
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest || [])
```

I am really stuck there as all documentation on workbox relates to leveraging cache. I am leveraging localforage as it supports promises which is what is required to make offline capability working.

Thanks

Comment: *I am leveraging localforage as it supports promises which is what is required to make offline capability working.* Could you explain what you mean by that? The [Cache Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage) is also uses promises and operates asynchronously, and it's definitely designed to handle this use case.

Comment: I was metionning that to explained why i was using Localforage instead of IDB.  but i want to leverage such storage because it is also part of standard recommednations (https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/live-data-in-the-service-worker) : "A general guideline for data storage is that URL addressable resources should be stored with the Cache interface, and other data should be stored with IndexedDB. For example HTML, CSS, and JS files should be stored in the cache, while JSON data should be stored in IndexedDB." I understand my life would be easier with Cache Storage.

Comment: *URL addressable resources should be stored with the Cache interface*... your JSON data originates from an HTTP API, and has a corresponding URL (beginning with the `/api/` path in your example), so it's URL addressable. I'd recommend sticking with the Cache Storage API for this use case.

Comment: Thanks Jeff,  this is certainly what I will do but I am surprised to see that integration with IDB is not covered anywhere as it is part of the standard recipes to maintain a local database. the API is a backend i am building and when I will have to post Data. my plan was also to leverage service worker to sync data. Maintaining a clean IDB store is making sense.

Comment: @GeraldM: I have the same set up as yours in one of my local project (which is in angular 6) like reading using localforage as a fallback response in offline mode. The only thing is I have `registerroute` on firebase API. The catch handler does gets called but my custom response fails. I am returning the response as well. But still its not working. Any idea ? I am trying this on localhost and not a live environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `catch()` handler needs to return either a `Response` object, or a promise for a `Response` object.

Adjusting the formatting of your sample code a bit, you're currently doing:

```
.catch(function (error) {
  console.warn(`Constructing a fallback response, due to an error while fetching the real response:, ${error}`)
  localforage.getItem(event.url.pathname).then((res) => {
    let payload = new Response(JSON.stringify(res), { "status" : 200 , "statusText" : "MyCustomResponse!" })
    console.log(payload)
    return payload
  })
})
```

Based on that formatting, I think it's clearer that you're not returning either a `Response` or a promise for a `Response` from within your `catch()` handler—you're not returning anything at all.

Adding in a `return` before your `localforage.getItem(...)` statement should take care of that:

```
.catch(function (error) {
  console.warn(`Constructing a fallback response, due to an error while fetching the real response:, ${error}`)
  return localforage.getItem(event.url.pathname).then((res) => {
    let payload = new Response(JSON.stringify(res), { "status" : 200 , "statusText" : "MyCustomResponse!" })
    console.log(payload)
    return payload
  })
})
```

But, as mentioned in the comments to your original question, I don't think that using IndexedDB to store this type of URL-addressable data is necessary. You can just rely on the Cache Storage API, which Workbox will happily use by default, when storing and retrieving JSON data obtained from an HTTP API.

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot. I will definitively create another version leveraging Cache Storage API and see if it covers all the use cases that the application will have to cover.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I must admit the Cache storage API is doing a great job. one line of code and then it is done. I learned a lot through this experience and it important to experiment to know which options are the most valuable. So far, Workbox is working very well.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: Hi @JeffPosnick. We are trying to make an app offline. But we are using SOAP APIs and the URL endpoint will always be the same with respect to any web service that our application triggers. In this case, how should we handle API response when user if offline. Since Cache API is URL based, is there any way to handle this scenario using cache API?